# About the automorphism groups of the objects in a connected groupoid

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

In the note named [Foundation of Algebraic Geometry](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/), the author gives an example: given a topological space $X$, there is a fundamental groupoid which is the category in which the objects are points of $X$, and morphisms $x\rightarrow y$are paths from $x$ to $y$ up to homotopy. We see the automorphism group $Aut(x)=\pi_1(X,x)$ is the fundamental group.

Then, the author points out that

> In the case where $X$ is connected, and $\pi_1(X)$ is not abelian, this illustrates the fact that for a connected groupoid, the automorphism groups of objects are all isomorphic, but not canonically isomorphic.

I don't understand this words. I see that in a connected groupoid, all objects are isomorphic to each other, thus their automorphism groups are all isomorphic. But why aren't they "canonically isomorphic"? What does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

It means that while an isomorphism between fundamental groups at various points always exists, it's not unique if the fundamental group is non-abelian. To see this, consider two paths $h,h'$ from $x$ to $y$.

Note that $\gamma\mapsto h\gamma h^{-1}$ and $\gamma\mapsto h'\gamma h'^{-1}$ are both isomorphisms $\pi_1(X,x)\to \pi_1(X,y)$, but they are distinct unless $\gamma_0=h^{-1}h'$ is in the center of  $\pi_1(X,x)$ (as you can write the latter as $\gamma\mapsto (h\gamma_0)\gamma (h\gamma_0)^{-1}=h(\gamma_0\gamma\gamma_0^{-1})h^{-1}$). So in particular, if $\pi_1(X,x)$ is abelian, they are always the same, and conversely, if any the isomorphism is unique, the group must be abelian.

Comment: So, does "canonically isomorphic" mean that there is exactly one isomorphism?

Comment: @stochastic: Generally, no. The word "canonical" does not have a set meaning throughout mathematics. If something is unique, then it definitely is canonical, but the converse is not true. For instance, if $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, then there is a canonical isomorphism between $V$ and $V^{**}$, but it is not the only isomorphism (if $V$ is not trivial).

Comment: Typically, when we say that something is canonical, we mean that there is either some "natural" construction that yields it (for example. it is basically built into the structures in question), or that it is actually a functor or a natural transformation of some sort (as is the case for the isomorphism $V\to V^{**}$).

Comment: Mind, in the example considered here, the isomorphism may be canonical (as in, it is the only isomorphism obtained in this way) but it is never the only isomorphism, unless the fundamental group has at most two elements. This is because every group with more than two elements has a nontrivial automorphism.